# Issue with AnnotationDbi: "None of the keys entered are valid keys"

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am very new to single cell RNA seq and I was trying to get the gene names using the same code from the tutorial but I keep getting an error:

```
GeneNameSymbol <- AnnotationDbi::select(org.Mm.eg.db, keys= GeneNameEnsembl, columns='SYMBOL', keytype='ENSEMBL')
```

this is the code I am using above, and the error is :

> Error in .testForValidKeys(x, keys, keytype, fks) :    object
> 'GeneNameEnsembl' not found

when I try

```
GeneNameSymbol <- AnnotationDbi::select(org.Mm.eg.db, keys='GeneNameEnsembl', columns='SYMBOL', keytype='ENSEMBL')
```

I get this error :

> Error in .testForValidKeys(x, keys, keytype, fks) :    None of the
> keys entered are valid keys for 'ENSEMBL'. Please use the keys method
> to see a listing of valid arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Check all possible *keys* for the db, then *select*, see example:

```
library(AnnotationDbi)
library(org.Mm.eg.db)

head(keys(org.Mm.eg.db))
# [1] "11287" "11298" "11302" "11303" "11304" "11305"

AnnotationDbi::select(org.Mm.eg.db,
                      keys = "11287",
                      columns = "SYMBOL")
#   ENTREZID SYMBOL
# 1    11287    Pzp
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering if it's possible to select all keys instead of calling one specific one because later i would want to link it to my monocle object (cds)

Comment: @Maryam of course, `keys =` can take more than one key.